# Addition and subtraction of wildcard masks

Tags: bit-manipulation

Wildcard masks are commonly used in networking.

Wildcard masks typically have "wildcard" bits that mean that bit can be both a 0 or a 1.
This binary wildcard mask (where the x's represent the wild-card bit)

```
10xx
```

covers all these values:

```
1000
1001
1010
1011
```

Is there a efficient way of adding/subtracting bit masks?
For example...

```
x011 + 0111 + xx01 + xxx0 + 1111 = xxxx
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "adding/subtracting bit masks"? Do you mean combining bit masks to cover additional bits?

Comment: I suppose you can use logical OR for adding bit masks.

Comment: Hmm. I have never seen a bit mask with the "wildcard" bits that you describe. I can't imagine how that even makes sense. By definition, a bit mask consists exclusively of 0s and 1s. You combine bit masks by using bitwise arithmetic: AND, OR, XOR, NOT. It is quite unclear to me what you are asking here—what would `xxxx` be represented as?

Comment: There is, but what that way is depends on how you represent the wildcards. Eg you might have pairs of "known/value", or "can be 0/can be 1", there are others. How do you represent them?

Comment: Hm, I probably used the wrong terminology here. I guess these aren't bitmasks, but wildcard masks. A binary wildcard mask xxxx would cover the decimal numbers from 0-15 (inclusive).

Comment: @acz yes it's clear what it means, but how do you represent xxxx

Answer (score 0):

There are several common ways to represent bitmasks with wildcards, here's how to compute the "join" (union of the sets represented by the inputs, then "rounded up" to the strictest mask that encompasses at least that set) for them

## Known/value

Consists of a pair of masks, `known, value` (k,v for short), where `known` has a 1 iff a bit has a fixed value, 0 for a wildcard. `value` has the values of non-wildcard bits, for wildcard bits the value is not relevant by itself but it simplifies the math if you choose it 0.

The representations of the masks from the example would be

```
      known value
x011  0111  0011
0111  1111  0111
xx01  0011  0001
xxx0  0001  0000
1111  1111  1111
```

The join of two of them, `(kr, vr) = (ka, va) ⋁ (kb, vb)` is

```
kr = ka & kb & ~(va ^ vb) // known if known in both inputs and same value
vr = va & kr   // value is the same as in either input, with wildcards normalized to 0
```

## Z,O

Confusing name, but it's a pair of masks where Z (zero) has a 1 iff the bit can be 0 (so it's either 0 or a wildcard) and O (one) has a 1 iff the bit can be 1 (so it's either 1 or a wildcard). Compared to known/value it has some pros and cons,

- More symmetric. Computations for Z and O are usually either the same or "dual", whereas computations for known and value are fundamentally different.
- Can represent the empty set. Whether this is a pro or a con depends on what you're doing. When a bit is 0 in both Z and O, that means the bit cannot have any value.
- Usually the math is more efficient, OTOH it's often harder to think about. The join is easy though.

The representations of the masks from the example would be

```
      Z     O
x011  1100  1011
0111  1000  0111
xx01  1110  1101
xxx0  1111  1110
1111  0000  1111
```

The join of two of them, `(zr, or) = (za, oa) ⋁ (zb, ob)` is

```
zr = za | zb
or = oa | ob
```